# How to gracefully cancel a cdk deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, github-actions, aws-cdk

### Issue

In my case I want to build a CI/CD pipeline with following requirements (using github actions):

- each git push triggers a workflow (= pipeline)
- each workflow creates/updates multiple stacks for the current branch (so each branch has its own deployment with its own independent stacks)
- if stacks for the branch are already deployed, the stacks get updated
- a `cdk deploy` command is used to create/update the stacks

This all works fine as long as you don't push new changes multiple times within a shorter time frame. If you push the first time it will trigger a `cdk deploy` as expected.
But if you push a second time shortly after, it will trigger a `cdk deploy` which is failing because previous `cdk deploy` already put the stacks in a `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` or `UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS` state. This is unfortunate because only the latest push and thus the latest `cdk deploy` is relevant.

### Question

How to gracefully cancel a `cdk deploy`, so it starts to rollback the deployment and a subsequent `cdk deploy` is able to succeed?

### I tried

The ideal solution for me would be that interrupting a `cdk deploy` command with `Ctrl+C` cancels the deployment. But this is not the case. It will just continue deploying. Is there another solution, **that is not overly complicated**?

Comment: CDK eventually is AWS cloudformation in the backend. So, if you could somehow hook this in the subsequent deploys, it could work.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/cancel-update-stack.html

Comment: I see this has been requested as a feature which is yet to be implemented : https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3781

Comment: @DevangSanghani I actually found that command but it says: `You can cancel only stacks that are in the UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS state.` To my understanding it means that you are not able to use this command when a stack is being created for the first time..

Comment: @DevangSanghani regarding the github issue: I already saw that and gave it a bump :D I might add another comment to it

Answer (score 0):

This question is highly opiniated and what the solution to your problem might not be to play with CDK at all. You can't be 100% sure that even after force cancelling the `cdk deploy` command it will rollback perfectly. What if the stack is deploying 1st time and creating s3 buckets. In this case even if you cancel the deployment. S3 bucket will NOT be deleted.

A straight forward solution to your problem is to implement sequential pipelines in your CI server. So if 1 pipeline is working for a given queue or repo then other pipeline should wait in a queue. By doing this your infra changes will be deployed incrementally. This is a much cleaner and sure shot solution to achieve what you're trying to do.

This ^ solution is not perfect like any other solution! It might create lot of slowness in the overall solution as sequential pipeline will take more time compared with cancel deployment -> delete stack -> redeploy.

Comment: meh. :D I see your point but we migrated to github actions from an older pipeline to improve pipeline performance. In that manner it seems to be counterproductive for my case at least. Also I wouldn't care if e.g. the S3 bucket is not deleted properly. My main goal is that subsequent pipeline runs never block each other but still maintain good speed. Cleanup needs to be handled differently anyway. All in all it seems like there is no good solution for this, which is pretty sad for such a huge platform as AWS..